# Is $\frac{4x + 2}{12 x ^2}$ simplifiable?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

I'd like to know what methods can I apply to simplify the fraction  $\frac{4x + 2}{12 x ^2}$

Is it valid to divide above and below by 2? (I didn't know it but Geogebra's Simplify aparantly does this)

Thanks in advance

Comment: HINT: $4x+2=2(2x+1)$. So you have $\frac{2(2x+1)}{12x^2}$. Can you see now that both numerator and denominator have a common factor of 2?

Comment: You can write it as $\dfrac{4x+2}{12x^2} = \dfrac{4x}{12x^2}+\dfrac{2}{12x^2} = \dfrac{1}{3x}+\dfrac{1}{6x^2}$. I don't know if this counts as being simpler.

Comment: Yes, dividing top and bottom by $2$ will give a slightly simpler form $\frac{2x+1}{6x^2}$. That's probably all you are expected to do. For *certain purposes* further manipulation would be useful. For example if I wanted to integrate I would transform to $\frac{1}{3x}+\frac{1}{6x^2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Factor out the $2$ from both the numerator and denominator. That is,
$$\require{cancel}\frac{4x+2}{12x^2}=\frac{\cancel{2}(2x+1)}{\cancel{2}\cdot6x^2}=\frac{2x+1}{6x^2}.$$

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are multiplying by $1$ in the form $\dfrac {\frac 12}{\frac 12}$, which takes you to $\frac {2x+1}{6x^2}$  That is all you can do

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a formula that can be evaluated with a minimal number of bit operations for any given $x$, it might be best to multiply by $\frac{\frac14}{\frac14}$ and get $$\frac{x+\frac12}{3x^2}$$ which in binary would be $$\frac{x+0.1}{11\cdot x^{10}}$$

Comment: Important point here is that the meaning of "simplification" is context-dependent. What is simplest for one purpose may be non-optimal for another purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can factor out a two from the numerator and denominator to get $$\frac{2x+1}{6x^2}.$$  multiplying the numerator and the denominator by the same number will never affect the value of the fraction.